# Hybrid animals: Where IS it?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

There is a game, Hybrid animals.
It is QUITE an interesting game. It has an FPS edition on steam and a MUCH different version on mobile.
My question is: WHy is there no tag for it? And why don't we add one?

Answer (score 3):

Tags cannot exist without questions asked. If no one has asked a question about Hybrid Animals, then the tag simply won't exist in our board. If you have a question for that game, ask it. If you don't have enough rep to create new tags, do your best to tag it appropriately, and another user with higher rep will assist.